# WPF "tooltip" popup flickers

Tags: wpf, popup, flicker

Long story short: I have a window that displays a bunch of charts in a ListBox. When mouseOver a chart (with LineSeries), there is a line that follows  the dataPoints (snaps to the dataPoint position). Near that line I'm presenting a tooltip made from a popup that presents info about those dataPoints.

[image: "tooltip" as it appears]

So far so good. The problem is when I try to move the mouse over the toolTip, the popup starts flickering (like its in an open/close loop). I've set already on the popup and on the children `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.

As a temp solution the popup "goes" out of the cursors way like here:

[image: "tooltip" repositioned]

...but is hardly "understandable".

Now comes the question: what's wrong? Why the popup starts flickering when the mouse is over it.

Any feedback welcome

PS. The tooltips XAML (it's created in code, but here it is):

The chart's datacontext is data bound to a class, also some chart's events are imlemented throught icommands. The popup is created in the constructor of that class,

```
ppchart = New Popup() With {.AllowsTransparency = True, .IsHitTestVisible = False,.StaysOpen = True}
```

...in the MouseMoveCommand the popup's child is created:

```
Dim ppCont As XElement = <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                     xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                     <Rectangle Opacity="0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="0" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Fill="#FFBABABA"/>
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Over, StringFormat=HH:mm}" FontSize="9" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1"/>
                                     <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="8" Margin="1,0,1,1" Grid.Row="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                         <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                                                 <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                                                 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                                 <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                                             </Style>
                                         </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                             <DataTemplate>
                                                 <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                     <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Culoare}" Width="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Operation}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding points.Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                                                 </Grid>
                                             </DataTemplate>
                                         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                     </ListBox>
                                 </Grid>

        ppchart.Effect = New Effects.DropShadowEffect() With {.Opacity = 0.5, .BlurRadius = 5, .Direction = 80, .Color = Colors.Black}
        ppchart.Child = CType(XamlReader.Load(New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(ppCont.ToString))), UIElement)
```

reedited: this is how it looks like

[image]

Comment: Can post the XAML used for the tooltip?

Comment: Why are you setting IsHitTestVisible? Did you try it without?

Comment: First time I tried without setting it at all and it was flickering also...

Comment: What event are you triggering the tooltip on?

Comment: the MouseMove of the chart is bound to a command. In that command I'm creating the popup's child, creating the datacontext for it, and setting the PopUp.IsOpen="True" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments I believe you are using the incorrect event; a `MouseMove` event will be continually trigged and with each time the popup to show/hide or flicker.

You want to use the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events.

Comment: I tried it already, but I have to check whether  the datapoint value the mouse is over changed or not (now you would say to attach it to the datapoint's `MouseEnter` or `MouseLeave`, but being a `LineSeries` I set the width/height of the datapoints to 0, I needed just the line. Anyway in the `MouseMove` i check before "re-opening" the PopUp is the value is different...

Comment: Funny thing. When the mouse is over the ToolTip, the `ChartMouseLeave` (in which I set `popup.IsOpen="False"` is triggered...

Comment: What charting middleware are you using?

Comment: It's Delay's edition for WPF (SL toolkit charts  at the base): [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/26/if-they-can-build-it-they-will-come-enabling-anyone-to-compile-wpf-charting-from-the-silverlight-charting-sources.aspx), but it's kinda modified to support  multi series binding (using Jeremiah Morrill's ideea + weakevents support to behave properly), threshold line(s), zooming & crosshair behavior....

Comment: i marked your reply as "the answer" because it helped me looking into the thing more careful. I dropped the use of `PopUp`. I use a `Grid` only and it work as expected.

Comment: @RaduC: Thanks, however do not feel that I "earned" it. I checked my implementation of tooltip this morning and found that I use a `MouseLeaveEvent` and `MouseMoveEvent` so that I re-use the existing `Popup`. Perhaps the flicker was been caused by your entry event re-creating the `Popup`.

Comment: true @Dennis. But curios for me is why when the mouse is over the `PopUp` and if you handle the underlying `UIElement`'s `MouseLeaveEvent` the latter event is triggered....

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar problem while using the **MouseEnter** and **MouseLeave** events. There is a strange behaviour of the **MouseEnter** event on WPF, don't know if it's a bug. When you enter the item in consideration from the top the flickering happens. Entering the item from any other direction gives you a smooth popup. So to avoid it, I removed the:

```
AllowsTransparency = True
```

part.

**EDITED:**

While still unable to find a perfect behaviour to my need, I figured out that this isn't actually a bug as described by Scott Hanselman [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MouseEnterAndMouseLeaveLoopsInWPF.aspx)

However I wasn't able to compare the problem to mine and sort it out. Anyway, to have the animation features, I came up with a solution that would atleast reduce the extra opening or closure of the Popup control by checking the current position of the mouse. I defined a variable

```
Point currPoint = new Point();
```

And then in the MouseEnter event or handler:

```
   ListViewItem listViewItem = e.Source as ListViewItem;           
        if(currPoint!=e.GetPosition(listViewItem))
            compToStrategyVM.OpenPopup(listViewItem, listViewPopup);
```

Similarly in the MouseLeave event or handler:

```
ListViewItem listViewItem = e.Source as ListViewItem;
        if (currPoint != e.GetPosition(listViewItem))
            compToStrategyVM.ClosePopup(listViewPopup);
```

Here `compToStrategyVM` refers to my ViewMode and `listViewPopup` refers to the name of the Popup control. Though the issue still persists, but by this approach the flickering effect has been reduced to a considerable fraction.

Comment: Only drawback is you can't use the Popup animation features which requires the above variable set to 'true'